# Sign of components of $\vec{L}$ seems to change under parity; book says otherwise

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors, geometry, parity

Book: Gravitational Waves-Vol 1 by Maggiore; pg 147, note 48

The book says that the components of angular momentum $\vec{L}$ are unchanged under parity (reversing the orientation of the axes).

Now, whether I think of $\vec{L}$ as

1. $\vec{r}\times \vec{p}$ using the right-hand rule (as taught in introductory physics) OR
2. $\epsilon^{i}_{jk} r^{j} p^{k}  $

(where $\epsilon^{i}_{jk}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor), I find that the sign of components of $L^i$ flips. Why is there this discrepancy between my conclusion and the book?

PS: When the axes orientation is reversed, a right-handed coordinate system becomes a left-handed one and the sign of components of the Levi-Civita tensor flips, thus changing the sign of $\epsilon^{i}_{jk} r^{j} p^{k} $.

Comment: The sign of the Levi-Civita symbol does not change under parity.

Comment: @Buzz Pg 82 of Sean Carroll's book says that the Levi-Civita symbol does change sign under right-handed to left-handed coordinate system transformation. When I reverse the orientation of the axes, I change from right to left-handedness.

Comment: I don't remember what Sean says in his book.  However, there is an issue of passive versus active transformations that you are probably misunderstanding.

Comment: I am trying to work in the passive sense.

Comment: There is no physics in passive transformations, just a relabeling of the coordinates.  You cannot learn anything new by looking at the passive transformations.

Comment: I think the book uses $\epsilon$ to represent the Levi-Civita symbol and not the Levi-Civita tensor. That's the only possible resolution of the problem that I can think of.